# How to fix font render bold chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts, rendering

I'm having problem with font rendering on chrome:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPP8u.png)

CSS:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto-Bold";
    font-display: auto;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('https://static.mediacdn.vn/tuoitre/web_font/Roboto-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'), url('https://static.mediacdn.vn/tuoitre/web_font/Roboto-Bold.woff') format('woff'), url('https://static.mediacdn.vn/tuoitre/web_font/Roboto-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'), url('https://static.mediacdn.vn/tuoitre/web_font/Roboto-Bold.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
}
.test {
    color: #222;
    font: normal 15px/normal Roboto-Bold;
    line-height: 18px;
    min-width: 90% !important;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" title="" claas="test">Font error with scroll in chrome!</a>
```

Comment: please tell me with any help!

Answer (score 0):

Your Code :
font-family: "Roboto-Bold";

Solution :
font-family: "Roboto";

Try using a normal roboto instead of the bold one because Roboto-Bold by default loads bold font weight.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I tried with Arial font, but the problem is still not solved, is this a display error from chrome?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:- Your Mistake Class spelling

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto-Bold";
    font-display: auto;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('https://static.mediacdn.vn/tuoitre/web_font/Roboto-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'), url('https://static.mediacdn.vn/tuoitre/web_font/Roboto-Bold.woff') format('woff'), url('https://static.mediacdn.vn/tuoitre/web_font/Roboto-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'), url('https://static.mediacdn.vn/tuoitre/web_font/Roboto-Bold.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
}
.test {
    color: #222;
    font: normal 15px/normal Roboto-Bold;
    line-height: 18px;
    min-width: 90% !important;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" title="" class="test">Font error with scroll in chrome!</a>
```